# How to populate an existing array with data from a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Objects inside existing array:

```
[
    {
        "contact": {
            "email": {
                "home": "",
            },
            "phone": {
                "cell": "+91-1234-567-891",
                "work": ""
            }
        },
        "createdDate": "2016-12-21T07:17:44.096Z",
        "name": "Test"
    },
    {
        "contact": {
            "email": {
                "home": "",
            },
            "phone": {
                "cell": "+91-1234-567-892",
                "work": ""
            }
        },
        "createdDate": "2016-12-21T07:17:44.096Z",
        "name": "Test2"
    }
]
```

New Array data:

```
[
    {
        "contact": {
            "email": {
                "home": "sample@gmail.com",
            },
            "phone": {
                "cell": "+91-1234-567-891",
                "work": ""
            }
        },
        "createdDate": "2016-12-21T07:17:44.096Z",
        "name": "Test1"
    },
    {
        "contact": {
            "email": {
                "home": "",
            },
            "phone": {
                "cell": "+91-1234-567-892",
                "work": ""
            }
        },
        "createdDate": "2016-12-21T07:17:44.096Z",
        "name": "Test2"
    },
    {
        "contact": {
            "email": {
                "home": "",
            },
            "phone": {
                "cell": "+91-1234-567-893",
                "work": ""
            }
        },
        "createdDate": "2016-12-21T07:17:44.096Z",
        "name": "Test3"
    }
]
```

If you see, there is extra object added inside new array and I have to populate existing array with new data.

Some times, user might change their email address and I have to update the same in existing array from new array. How do I do this?

with what I have tried, its duplicating the objects inside existing array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < oldArray.length; k++){
            if(newArr[i].contact.phone.cell && newArr[i].contact.phone.cell === oldArray[k].contact.phone.cell){
                console.log('MATCHED...........', newArr[i]);
                newArr.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there only one object within "existing" array?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest For now, yes only one object but it might add up with more objects from new array when ever there is new data

Comment: why do you need to copy data over. Can't you just use the new data?

Comment: Is there something not working with your code?

Comment: @SimonH Well, I have data inside my no-sql database(rethink db) in the form of array and I want to populate new data into it. Replacing all the data would not right i guess

Comment: @GG. its popluating existing array with duplicates objects from new array

Comment: @GG. The object with `"cell": "+91-1234-567-891",` is added twice. So I am thinking there is some thing wrong with what I am doing

Comment: You can use *Array.prototype.concat()* if you want to join 2 arrays or just use *Array.protoypr.push()* to add a singe element on one. I think you could even use *concat()* and generate a new array (this have some valuable reasons). In your case you should change the data type and have a list of *email* rather that have a list of contacts that have just different email.

Comment: @MarioSantini Each contact object belongs to each user. I am trying fetch contact list from google api when user authenticates

Comment: You won't loop over all `newArr`elements as `newArr.length` hence element indexes will change after `newArr.splice()` is called within the loop.

Comment: @SLePort then how do I remove the elements that are already present in existing array?

Comment: You can reverse the loop order: `for(var i = newArr.length; i--;) {`

Comment: @SLePort How will that solve? Increasing or decreasing `i` variable is same I think if I am not wrong?

Comment: No, by incrementing, indexes will not reference same elements after a `splice()`. If you delete first object, next one becomes `myarray[0]` and your loop will process `myarray[1]`. You can avoid this issue by starting from the end.